# onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'htmltools' when starting shiny App in R

Tags: r, shiny

I am suddenly getting the following error when trying to start a shiny App from within RStudio:

```
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'htmltools', details:
  call: get(genname, envir = envir)
  error: object 'knit_print' not found
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘shiny’ was built under R version 3.1.2 
 Show Traceback

 Rerun with Debug
 Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘shiny’
```

I tried to reinstall htmltool but it does not fix the problem.
Can anyone help?

Comment: yes I have: the command "library(knitr)" or "require(knitr)" is accepted by R. However the function "knit_print" still unknown. As if it is a path problem....

Comment: Have you `update.packages()`?